# Why am I seeing weird values for watermarks without a source configured to emit watermarks in flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have some tests for a flink application where I bootstrap some test data something like this

```
final WatermarkStrategy<Event> noWatermarks = WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks();

final DataStream<MyEvent> myDataStream = env.fromElements(myEvent1, myEvent2);
myDataStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(noWatermarks)
```

Then I connect it to a sink

```
mySink.connect(myDataStream);
```

However, when I look at the sink, I see some weird values for the watermark

[image]

Why am I seeing this watermark value when I am explicitly asking it not to use watermark?

Comment: I think I figured out the reason. https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/eventtime/Watermark.html. When a source reaches the end of the input, it emits a final watermark with timestamp Long.MAX_VALUE, indicating the "end of time". Since it is a bounded stream, it emitted that watermark at the end